# Dynamically add class/id onclick

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multiple divs, I want this so when the user clicks an option (A,B,C,D) this divs class is then added to the roller-banner, so I can then target the roller-banners CSS colour.

I have created the following codepen I want to grab whatever class has been clicked e.g. colour3, then add 'colour3' as an ID or class to the roller-banner div.

Pen- https://codepen.io/scottYg55/pen/WNNgxWZ

```js
$(".changecolours > div").on('click', function() {
  var colourChange = this.value;
  $('.roller-banner').attr('class', colourChange);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="changecolours">
  <div class="colour1">A</div>
  <div class="colour2">B</div>
  <div class="colour3">C</div>
  <div class="colour4">D</div>
</div>

<div class="roller-banner">
  <img src="http://www.project-progress.co.uk/dropbox/global/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/roller-banner-nodetails.png" class="static">

  <div class="halft-colour"></div>
  <div class="halfb-colour"></div>

  <div class="dlogo">
    <img src="http://www.project-progress.co.uk/dropbox/global/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/select-dropbox.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="instertxt">
    <div id="yourtextlive"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dpimg">
    <img src="http://www.project-progress.co.uk/dropbox/global/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/banner-insert-img.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="dplink">
    dropbox.com
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: And the problem you're having/question is...?

Comment: The class isnt being added to roller-banner. I want the class of what has been clicked from changecolours, to be added to roller-banner. e.g. If click .colour2, colour2 then adds to roller-banner by either class or id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that you're clicking on a `div` - that doesn't have a property `value`. Better to store the "colour" as a data attribute.

You can also store this selection on the `roller-banner` element, making it easy to remove this class when a different one is selected.

```js
$(".changecolours > div").on('click', function() {
  var colourChange = $(this).data("color");
  $('.roller-banner').removeClass(function(){ return $(this).data("selected-color")})
                     .data("selected-color",colourChange)
                     .addClass(colourChange);
});
```

```css
.colour1{ background-color:red}
.colour2{ background-color:green}
.colour3{ background-color:orange}
.colour4{ background-color:blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="changecolours">
  <div data-color="colour1">A</div>
  <div data-color="colour2">B</div>
  <div data-color="colour3">C</div>
  <div data-color="colour4">D</div>
</div>

<div class="roller-banner">
  <img src="http://www.project-progress.co.uk/dropbox/global/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/roller-banner-nodetails.png" class="static">

  <div class="halft-colour"></div>
  <div class="halfb-colour"></div>

  <div class="dlogo">
    <img src="http://www.project-progress.co.uk/dropbox/global/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/select-dropbox.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="instertxt">
    <div id="yourtextlive"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dpimg">
    <img src="http://www.project-progress.co.uk/dropbox/global/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/banner-insert-img.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="dplink">
    dropbox.com
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```